# How to make logo and button responsive in squarespace?

Tags: html, css, mobile, squarespace, responsiveness

https://riketest.squarespace.com/

This is the website I'm working on. the logo or button move when I make the screen smaller. I need to stay like that while getting smaller until it gets to a certain size for mobile.

Keep in mind, I'm using Squarespace so there are certain restrictions. I need the logo on top of the buttons at all times but it seems to fall out of place when it comes to tablet and mobile.

Help me, please

Comment: Hey Haitham Mousa, can you share some code, that you can change in Squarespace and that are related to your issue, with us ? (HTML/CSS in that case)

Comment: @Alex-dejauneetdebleu I've tried using this `@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  {  
  .homelogo {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
     margin-left: -25px;
    display: block;
    
  }
}` hasn't helped me much. Can you recommend any code